# mean.io / no matching version found for ajv@undefined

Tags: npm, mean, ajv

I wanted to run mean.io and got this error after **npm install**.

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ajv@undefined
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are 
requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)** insted of **NPM** ( Tested for MEAN v2.0.1 )

**MEAN Installation**

```
yarn install
yarn build
yarn start
```

More Info: https://github.com/linnovate/mean